# JPA, get value of additional column from joinable table

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, join

I have 3 tables (T_BONUS_TAB, T_COND, T_BONUS_COND_LINK). 
One of them connects (T_BONUS_COND_LINK) two other tables.

This table has 3 columns: bonus_id, cond_id (references to parent tables) and another column with additional value (priority).

```
create table T_BONUS_COND_LINK
(
  cond_id   NUMBER(9) not null,
  bonus_id NUMBER(9) not null,
  priority NUMBER(1)
)
alter table T_BONUS_COND_LINK
 add constraint T_BONUS_COND_B_FK foreign key (BONUS_ID)
  references T_BONUS_TAB (ROW_ID);
alter table T_BONUS_COND_LINK
 add constraint T_BONUS_COND_M_FK foreign key (COND_ID)
  references T_COND (ROW_ID);
```

The question is how get value of priority column?

```
@Entity(name = ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = "T_BONUS_TAB")
@Customizer(EclipseLinkIssuesFixer.class)
public class BonusApplication extends AbstractIdentifiableByLongEntity {
      ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER)
   @JoinTable(
        name="T_BONUS_COND_LINK",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="BONUS_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="COND_ID")
   )
   private List<Condition> conds;
   ....
}

@Entity(name = ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = "T_COND")
@Customizer(EclipseLinkIssuesFixer.class)
public class CONDITION extends AbstractIdentifiableByLongEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ROW_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "NAME", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "DESCX", updatable = false)
   private String desc;
}
```

Comment: And where is "this additional column" mapped in your Java model? It's not? in which case you can only use SQL queries to access it, and then lose portability. JPA is for object-oriented systems

Comment: it's not mapped, because now I search the way how can i do this.

Comment: As already said ... not mapped means you cannot use JPQL to get the data. Mapped means you can use JPQL. There are ample posts on this site with people wanting a join table with additional column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must map the T_BONUS_COND_LINK table as a regular entity with a composite primary key.

You have to create an ID Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class BonusCondLinkId {
    Long bonusId;
    Long condId;
    ...
}
```

That you can use like this:

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(BonusCondLinkId.class)
public class BonusCondLink {
    @Id
    private Long bonusId;
    @Id
    private Long condId;
    ...
}
```

Or as an EmbeddedId:

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(BonusCondLinkId.class)
public class BonusCondLink {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BonusCondLinkId id;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will apply such way:

```
@Embeddable
public class BonusCondLinkId implements Serializable {

   private long bonusId;
   private long condId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="T_BONUS_COND_LINK")
@IdClass(BonusCondLinkId.class)
public class BonusCondLink implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name="bonus_id")
  private @Getter @Setter long bonusId;

  @Id
  @Column(name="cond_id")
  private @Getter @Setter long condId;

  @Column(name="priority")
  private @Getter @Setter Integer priority;

  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BONUS_ID", referencedColumnName="ROW_ID")
  private @Getter @Setter Bonus bonus;

  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CON_ID", referencedColumnName="ROW_ID")
  private @Getter @Setter Condition cond;

}

@Entity(name = ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = "T_BONUS")
@Customizer(EclipseLinkIssuesFixer.class)
public class Bonus extends AbstractIdentifiableByLongEntity {

   ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="bonus")
   @OrderBy("priority")
   private @Getter @Setter List<BonusCondLink> conditions;
}
```

and class Condition with @OneToMany(mappedBy="cond") by analogy with Bonus class.